# beanstalkd has a limit on tubename?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, beanstalkd

I was trying to add this tubename to beanstalkd "video_convert_and_snap". it gives me an error that this is an invalid tubename. Any idea, why?

Answer (score 1):

The server itself has not had this limitation for a while ([add '_' issue closed](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/issues/closed#issue/24) in March 2010, ahead of release v1.4.4) You may have an older version of the server running, or the client code may be erroneously checking for the character, and producing the error message.